# Setup NuGet.Config with TFS package source for a docker build

Tags: nuget

With the following NuGet.Config file, I'm getting this error message during a docker container build:

What's the correct way to setup NuGet.Config?

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.104/NuGet.targets(104,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json. [/src/Grains.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.104/NuGet.targets(104,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/src/Grains.sln]
```

I have not setup the authorization for the private nuget feed correctly.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
   <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
   <add key="MyCompany" value="https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/" />
  </packageSources>

  <!-- Used to store credentials -->
  <packageSourceCredentials />

  <apikeys>
    <add key="https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json" value="mytoken" />
  </apikeys>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Obviously, "mycompany", "myfeed", and "mytoken" are used as replacements here for the correct values... I'm not mistakenly using them in the build attempts!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyFeed" value="https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <MyFeed>
      <add key="Username" value="myemailid" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="mytoken" />
    </MyFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```